# Angular Signals - problems when using variables

Tags: angular, variables, signals

I am modifying all the variables in my angular project to be able to use Signals. In general I get it to work, but when I try to modify a variable that I later use in an ngOnInit, constructor or other function I can't get it to work.

Here is an example:

I create my variable

```
currentYear = signal<number>(0);
```

And when I want to use it, it tells me that Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'WritableSignal'.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;

    this.currentYear = moment().year();

    const currentDate = new Date();
    this.rangeDate[0] = currentDate;
    this.rangeDate[1] = moment(currentDate)
      .add(1, 'month')
      .startOf('month')
      .endOf('month')
      .toDate();
  }
```

How can I use my variables?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    this.currentYear = moment().year();
```

Should be

```
    this.currentYear.set(moment().year());
```

This is how signals work. Pay better attention to the documentation !